# Sync Track trigger not working

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, batch

This might be not directly a salesforce issue. I work in Veeva. There is sync tracking custom object in Veeva where records of User syncronization from Ipad is stored. I have to run a after insert trigger on that object that will instantiate a batch class. Though the trigger is compiled successfully it is not getting fired after creating a dummy sync record by creating a tab in salesforce. can someone help me her please?

Trigger:

```
trigger CallSync on Sync_Tracking_vod__c (after insert) {
Set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
List<Sync_Tracking_vod__c> SyncTrack=
            [SELECT  id,Successful_Sync_vod__c
                      FROM Sync_Tracking_vod__c
                     where id =:ids and Successful_Sync_vod__c=1];

     if(SyncTrack.isEmpty()==false)
     {  Boolean isExecuting = ([SELECT COUNT()
                    FROM AsyncApexJob
                   WHERE ApexClassId IN (
                                    SELECT Id
                                      FROM ApexClass
                                     WHERE Name = 'AckCallUpdatenew')] == 0) ? false : true ;
    if(isExecuting){
        return;
    }
    Database.executeBatch(new AckCallUpdatenew(),1);
     }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `not getting fired?`

Comment: The trigger compiles successfully but when creating a record in sync object I can't find the apex batch called from the trigger.

Comment: 1) ooh -- return statements in triggers - not good practice; 2) is successful_sync_vod a checkbox field or a number field; if checkbox compare to `true`, not `1`

Comment: Then what can be written here instead of return?

Comment: This is more logical
`if(!isExecuting){Database.executeBatch(new AckCallUpdatenew(),1);}`

Comment: It is a formula field - values 1.0 or 0.0

Comment: I did as you suggested still same issue happening.

Comment: two things: 1. Add `System.Debug()` right after the query of `AsyncApexJob` and check the status of `isExecuting` variable. 2. Add another `sys.debug` right after the `if(SyncTrack.isEmpty()==false) {...` statement to check whether you are getting inside of the `if`. Let us know something happens.